# Proper subsets with positive measure

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a probability space. If $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and $\mu(A)>0$, can I always find a proper measurable subset $S\subsetneq A$, $S\in\mathcal{A}$, with $\mu(S)>0$? 
I guess that this has to do somehow with the axiom of choice or something similar, and it seems quite reasonable to me, but I don't know much about measure theory and I'd like to be sure that we can always find such a subset, or at least whether there exist any reasonably nice conditions on $A$ under which the statement is true.

Thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the axiom of choice. It has to do with atomic measures, and non-atomic measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in general. For instance, let $X=\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ (the power set of $\mathbb{N}$) and for $A\in\mathcal{A}$, define
$$
\mu(A)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n\in A}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
(Where the sum over the empty set is assumed to be 0)
If you take take $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ and define $A=\{n_0\}$, then $\mu(A)>0$, however you can't find a measurable proper subset of $A$ with positive measure.

I think the concept you are looking for is that of [atom](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28measure_theory%29).

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about atomic and non-atomic measures, but that was exactly what I was looking for!